# Dynamically add table row when last row field clicked for the first time

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have a table which dynamically adds a row when the last row in the table is clicked. Specifically I have a row which have 2 text boxes and I would like to add a new row whenever a user clicks into either box.

The aim is to provide a growing list which would then have the option to delete rows etc. (but not specifically needed for this question!)

In my head the logic would work along the lines of

```
if (either text box clicked && is last row) then
  addrow()
```

Table [fiddle here:](https://jsfiddle.net/rajenmanani/srj9yxve/)

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" id="paramsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="text-center">key</th>
      <th class="text-center">value</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="param01">
      <td class="text-center">
        <label>
          <input class="vert-align" type="checkbox" value="">
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" id="paramKey01" type="text" aria-label="..." placeholder="key">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" id="paramVal01" type="text" aria-label="..." placeholder="value">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
      <button type="submit">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

An example of this functionality is if anyone uses 'postman' and the headers tab when building a request!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below scripts and add class `delete` to the delete button.

```
 $(document).on('click','tr:last-child input',function(){
   $(this).parents('tbody').append($(this).parents("tr").clone())
   $(this).parents('tr').find('input').val("");
 });

 $(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
   $(this).parents("tr").remove();
 });
```

Comment: thanks for this. is there any way to limit the on 'click' to just the two input boxes.. fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rajenmanani/srj9yxve/1/ and you can see that when ticking the checkbox it also adds a new row?

Comment: instead of 'tr:last-child input' try with 'tr:last-child input[type="text"]'

Answer (score 0):

You should use [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) to catch your desired element, and then trig [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) containing new field.